# I don't understand some libgdx compilation errors

Tags: java, libgdx

I am novice in Java and libgdx and don't understand something important there.
I try to get touch(mouse) events.
My code example worked okay before I added few lines in the code below:

```
    ...
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Buttons;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
...
public class Game implements ApplicationListener /*, InputProcessor*/
...
@Override
public void create() 
{
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this); 
    //*** ERROR:setInputProcessor(InputProcessor) in the type Input
    //is not applicable for the arguments Game
    ...
}
...

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) { 
        //*** ERROR: The method touchDown(int, int, int, int) of type Game 
        //must override or implement a supertype method     

        Gdx.app.log("Input Test", "touch down: " + x + ", " + y + ", button: " +
           getButtonString(button));
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I used [this example](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/InputTest.java)
Maybe I have to write"class InputTest extends GdxTest"?
But I got error if I insert "import com.badlogic.gdx.tests.utils.GdxTest;"

In many examples on the internet no "import" lines
and libraries name ,which should be added to the project.
Can anybody explain how to find out it?

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't the class implement `InputProcessor` any more?

Comment: You got *what* error? Posting vague statements like 'I got error' is a complete waste of time. It just leads to questions like this, and lost time.

Answer (score 2):

The first error

```
ERROR:setInputProcessor(InputProcessor) in the type 
Input is not applicable for the arguments Game
```

You are passing in the `this` reference which is of type `Game` but the `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor` wants a parameter that is a reference to an `InputProcessor` object

In order to fully understand the second error you need to understand Overriding
see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

If you uncomment the `implements InputProcessor` that should get rid of that error.

Comment: Yes. Compilation errors disappeared after I uncommented  "implements InputProcessor" and added all   @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode)  {
        Gdx.app.log("Input Test", "keyDown " + String.valueOf(keycode)); ... All works okay. Thank you.